# Giving "unreachable code" error

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

Good day. Can somebody help me. I can't seem to find a way to fix this problem. I don't know why i am getting "unreachable code" error when i close the InputStream and the socket..

Thank you for the help.

```
 public void run() {
          try {
           socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

           ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

           int bytesRead;
           InputStream inputStream;

           while (true) {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }
                textResponse.setText(response);
                if(response == "Server: You are connected to Android Server"){
                    Log.v("ok","ppp");
                }
                if(response == "OK"){
                    Log.v("ok","ooo");
                }
           }

           inputStream.close();    --------unreachable code
           socket.close();         --------unreachable code

          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
          } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
          }
  }
```

Comment: Control cannot come out of infinite loop so need to add some condition or break loop in some case.

Comment: `while(true)` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while (true) {}` is an endless loop and you're not breaking from it, hence the two `close()` statements being unreachable.

When your condition is met inside the `while` loop, you can use `break;` statement to continue executing the code below the `while`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

t    while (condition) { 
                    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

```
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }
                textResponse.setText(response);
                if(response == "Server: You are connected to Android Server"){
                    Log.v("ok","ppp");
                }
                if(response == "OK"){
                    Log.v("ok","ooo");
                }
           }
```

your `while (true)` is looping all the time. You need to break the while to go to next line. In your case it wont go to next line since while not ending. You may change **while** to **if**, it its not looping statements.